# Reload AsyncStorage data every time tabbar screen is displayed using React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage, tabnavigator

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) in a React Native app I'm building and I have a set of screens that are in a TabNavigator. One of the screens may change something in AsyncStorage which will need to reflected in another screen.

I tried various different things including setting the `tabBarOnPress` property in the `navigationOptions` of the second screen, but that did not work. I also tried using `componentDidUpdate()` and `componentWillUpdate()`, but nothing.

What is the accepted way to do this?

**UPDATE 1** I managed to have it such that I am capturing when the tab is pressed by doing

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Screen B',
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen B',
    tabBarOnPress: (obj) => {
      // load data here....

      // this causes this screen to actually appear
      obj.jumpToIndex(obj.scene.index)
     }
};
```

Now, I need to load the data in using

```
loadFavouritesData() {
    // load from AsyncStorage here and update state
}
```

However, using `this.loadFavouritesData()` in the arrow function in `tabBarOnPress` doesn't do it as it's not the correct `this`. What can I do after this?

Comment: Am I getting it right? You have screen A, which can update some data in the async storage, and screen B, which references these data while rendering. You want component B to re-render with the fresh data when the user navigates from A to B

Comment: @NikitaIsaev yes, pretty much.

Comment: what about `componentWillMount()` of screen B? It should fire when the component appears on the screen.

Comment: `componentWillUpdate()` fires only when props or state are changed, which is not the case. `componentWillMount()` should fire when your navigator renders it into the UI object model.

Comment: Yeah, `componentWillMount()` only fires once when the screen is initially loaded (not shown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to this. It's a rather hacky one but it works.

Carrying on from the update posted in the question, I further do this in `componentWillMount()`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
       currentScreen: this,
    })
}
```

This makes the `navigation` object carry around a reference to the current screen. I can then modify the `navigationOptions` to be an arrow function which takes a `navigation` object:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: 'Screen B',
    tabBarLabel: 'Screen B',
    tabBarOnPress: (obj) => {

       // load data here by getting currentScreen from the navigation params

       navigation.state.params.currentScreen.loadFavouritesData()
       obj.jumpToIndex(obj.scene.index)
    }
})
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it seems to work for now, at least until I start getting into Redux.

Comment: @YousserMoawad Do you know how to achieve the same thing if the `loadFavouritesData` is an `async` function? In my case, calling the async function makes the app crash